# Is there any automatic way to replace string concatenation with formatted string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, string-formatting

I have a js file which I want to change its textual content.

I want to change all string concatenation with formatted string.

Easy way free to replace these test options automatically?

Writing in python or any existing tool?

Say:

`Logger.log("My name is "+name+" Hi!");`

to

```
Logger.log(`My name is ${name} Hi!`);
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Those single quotes just replace with a back ticks, it looks very similar to a single quote.  On my keyboard it's the top left key under the esc key.

Comment: In VSCode at least, if you're dedicated, you can write a regex search and replace to do this.

Comment: @caTS It's not an easy one for me

Comment: @James True, but I try to find an auto replacement for an existing code.

Comment: In VSCode, when I click on some code that has a string concat, there is a light bulb icon which gives me the option to "Convert to template string".